# How to skip the item body in an inline description* list?

Tags: lists, enumitem, description, inline

I am having a simple doc:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinedesc}{description*}{1}
\setlist[inlinedesc]{itemjoin={{ $\odot$ }}, itemjoin*={{ and }}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7.2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{fussy}

Here comes \verb+inlinedesc+:

\begin{inlinedesc}
\item[first] about the first item
\item[second] THIS CANNOT BE EMPTY
\item[third] about the third item
\item[first] about the first item
\item[second] THIS CANNOT BE EMPTY
\item[third] about the third item
\end{inlinedesc}

more text ... more text ...

\end{fussy}
\end{document}
```

How do I get rid of `THIS CANNOT BE EMPTY`?
Just deleting it doesn't work:

```
! Package enumitem Error: Misplaced \item.
```

For some `inlinedesc` items I just want the head/term (with an empty body).

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `\item[second] \mbox{}`.

Comment: @frougon Thanks --- it works!

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to get around.

As frougon mentioned in the comments `\mbox{}` is one of the ways to go. However, you can use en empty group for that

```
\item[second] {}
```

or even simpler put a space character: either `~` or `\` both result the same

```
\item[second] ~
```

```
\item[second] \
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inlinedesc}{description*}{1}
\setlist[inlinedesc]{itemjoin={{ $\odot$ }}, itemjoin*={{ and }}}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{7.2pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{fussy}

Here comes \verb+inlinedesc+:

\begin{inlinedesc}
\item[first] about the first item
\item[second] {}
\item[third] about the third item
\item[first] about the first item
\item[second] ~
\item[third] about the third item
\item[second] \
\end{inlinedesc}

more text ... more text ...

\end{fussy}
\end{document}
```